# Using foreach and cs coordinates, foreach evaluate and axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I was trying to draw dots over a pgfplots axis using axis cs coordinates. This works just fine typing the coordinates by hand, but fails as soon as I try to use the value coming from a foreach statement. See MWE below. Any idea how I can remedy this? I tried using curly brackets, even just integers without any calculation seem to pose a problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \s in {0,0.25,0.5} {
    \fill (axis cs:\s,0.5) circle (1.5pt);
}

\addplot[domain=0:1] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In fact, I also run into a problem as soon I use the evaluate option of foreach, see MWE below. Any idea of what the issue is here?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \s using \x*10] in {0,1,..,10} {
        %
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be three dots. Not `in {0,1,..,10}`, but `in {0,1,...,10}`. Note that `pgfplots` already loads `tikz` and with `compat=1.18` set, you can omit `axis cs:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `\s` must be pre-expanded.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \s in {0,0.25,0.5} {
    \edef\tmp{(axis cs:\s,0.5)}%
    \expandafter\fill\tmp circle (1.5pt);
}

\addplot[domain=0:1] {x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, I am not sure what pre-expanded mean, what edef is, etc, but I am wondering isn't there any neater way? It is quite cumbersome to write every time, especially once you've already written an entire figure setting \s using \def before adding the \foreach statement.

Comment: Also what if you want to pass options to \fill, like \fill[blue], how does that work? It just returns an error.

Comment: @Cryme you could do `\edef\tmp{[blue] (axis cs:\s,0.5)}`.

Comment: That worked indeed! I think that solves the practical problem, but I am still wondering why it has to be so convoluted. Is there a different way of reaching the same result? or is this the usual way?

Comment: @Cryme There may be a less convoluted way, but I am no expert on `pgfplots` to know it.